# Oracle Apex doesn't show existing schema

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a problem with connecting data from my local oracle user schema (USERS table space) and apex workplace.
Could you adivise how I can connect apex workplace with my existing schema?
It looks like APEX uses its own table space and ignores my schemas.

Here are my screenshots:
[SQL Developer screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LWUn.png) [Creating a new workspace screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWcWC.png)

Forgot one significat thing to mention: schema Pavel in Apex and schema Pavel in SQL Developer are different. Tables, which are  created in the Apex in schema Pavel, are not seen in SQL Developer.

[No apex user screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InZHq.png)

[apex create workplace and new schema dialog (different table space), the schema is not visible in sql developer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASPm8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in misunderstanding oracle database architecture.
The APEX data was stored in the pluggable database, while the default connection  in SQL Plus was to the root container cdb$root.

alter session set container = XEPDB1;

Answer (score 0):

See whether following helps:

Connect to the database as `SYS` and check your Apex users:

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_USERS WHERE USERNAME LIKE 'APEX%',
```

Suppose there's `APEX_180200` listed (and you use it). Then:

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = APEX_180200;  

BEGIN  
    APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN.UNRESTRICT_SCHEMA(P_SCHEMA => 'ADAM');  
    COMMIT;  
END;  
/
```

Now check whether you can assign the `ADAM` schema to your workspace.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, no apex user was found. I attached the screen in the top message.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to add your existing schema to your APEX workspace:
check out oracle docs for this:https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_instance.htm#AEAPI253

```
 BEGIN
   APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN.ADD_SCHEMA('MY_WORKSPACE','FRANK');
 END;
```